# Python ```while``` loop for comparing strings not working as it should be

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, loops, while-loop

I am trying to take the value at [1,3] in a dataframe named df1 and compare it with another string; then write the dataframe to a csv file if both values are the same. the original value at df1.iat[1,3] i.e. var c is "Alayamon". But it still writes the dataframe to csv even when I intentionally changed the string to "Alayaon" to check if it is working. I want the code to print "waiting..." if the values are not the same and keep trying to read the dataframe until the dataframe with the correct value at df1.iat[1,3] is reached. Any suggestions on how I should change the code so that it writes the dataframe only when both variables are exactly similar?

````
df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(dfs[4].to_csv(index=False)), skiprows=1, header=[0,1])
c = df1.iat[1,3]
        print(c)
       
        c == "Alayaon"
        while True:
            try:
                df1.to_csv("break.csv", index=False)
                break
            except:
                if x:
                    print("waiting...")
                    x = False```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`c == "Alayaon"` Is a comparison not a allocation, it should be `c = "Alayaon"`

Additionally you never check for anything inside your loop. As is, your loop will always execute `df1.to_csv("break.csv", index=False)` unless it fails and then break out of the loop.

You'll need to change it to something like

```py
if(c == "Alayaon"):
    df1.to_csv("break.csv", index=False)
    break
else:
    print("waiting...")
```

```py
if x:
    print("waiting...")
    x = False
```

The above will not trigger since you don't have x declared and should run into an error.

Comment: Hi as you recommended I changed the code as below `while True:
            try:
                if(c == "Alayamon"):
                    df1.to_csv('breakwithGP.csv', mode='a', header=False)
                    print("GP1 over")
                    break
                else:
                    print("waiting...")
            except:
                print("not found")`. Now it is waitng for the correct dataframe, but does not read it to csv even when the correct one appears. Instead it keeps printing "waiting...". If not too much trouble, could you pls look into it once more?

Comment: @adcadmin Well for some reason it seems to not enter the if statement, have you checked if the values really match? Case sensitive etc.

Comment: Yes. They are one and same. I copied and pasted it to ensure it.

Comment: Well there has to be a reason the comparison fails, if it isn't mispelled then there might be a type error. I'd set a breakpoint at that line and check every comparison. if I copy and paste what you've commented, and set `c = "Alayamon"` before start it works perfectly fine.

Comment: in the comment you posted you're not updating the `c` variable inside the loop

Comment: Hi, thank you so much. I thought I was being too unreasonable asking for help again and again. That's why I deleted the comment. You are great for answering again. But this stuff is still too advanced for me. I don't know how to edit it further inside the loop. Could you please point me to some similar code where it is done in the right way?